# Route Configuration for displaying list & details component together

Tags: angular, routes, angular7, routeconfig

I am unable to fetch the id using paramMap because it is coming null.

Can someone help me to understand if there is anything wrong in the router configuration for displaying list & details component together?

most of the examples display the list > details navigation

app-routing.module.

```
path: 'environments',
canActivate: [AuthGuard],
loadChildren: './employee/employee.module#EmployeeModule'
```

employee-routing.module.ts

```
path: '',
component: ListComponent,
children: [
   {
     path: ':id',
     component: DetailComponent
   }
]
```

need to display list & details component together with details component changing as per the route param